# Nested styling within Typography

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

How can I style my text with `<Typography />` ? Is it possible to do something like this:

```
const someText = 'Hello <b>World</b>';

...
  <Typography>
   {someText}
  </Typography>
...
```

Or do I need to split up my text? With nested Typographies I seem to have some layout issues.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally made use of a custom style like this:

```
const styleSheet = createStyleSheet('SomeComponent', (theme) => ({
  root: {
  },
...
  body2Bold: {
    fontFamily: theme.typography.body2.fontFamily,
    fontSize: theme.typography.body2.fontSize,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
  },
}));
```

And then in my render function:

```
const { Hello, World, classes } = this.props;
...
    <Typography type="body2" color="default">
        {Hello}
        <span className={classes.body2Bold}>
          &nbsp;{World}
        </span>.
    </Typography>
...
```

The down side is that I need to break up some text into different variables.

Answer (score 7):

I'm using material-ui 4.* and doing this is perfectly legal.

```html
<Typography variant={'h5'} >Treffen Sie auf der it-sa 2019 die Micro Focus 
     <Typography display={'inline'} >und diskutieren Sie über </Typography>
</Typography>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Box Component](https://material-ui.com/system/typography/#FontWeight.js)

It accepts the properties `fontWeight` and `display` like this:

```html
<Typography component="div">
    This is normal text <Box display="inline" fontWeight="fontWeightBold">this is bold</Box>
</Typography>
```

> **NOTE:** Make sure you add `component="div"` to your `Typography` otherwise you'll get the following error:
>
> `<div>` cannot appear as a descendant of `<p>`

Here is a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/eager-star-wgo1u?fontsize=14)

Answer (score 0):

Use a basic `html` within the `Typography`

```
<Typography>
  Hello <b>World</b>
</Typography>
```

or

```
<Typography>
  Hello <span style={{ font-weight: 'bold' }}>World</span>
</Typography>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this will be the easiest one.

```js
import {styled} from "@mui/material";

const Span = styled("span")();

<Typography variant="body1">
  Hello <Span sx={{...}}>World</Span>
</Typography>
```